# Deleted 'Other Software' repositories

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, update-manager, repository, official-repositories

I recently loaded Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on my laptop and accidenly deleted all of the 'Other Software' repositories from the 'Software & Updates'. I can not find any way to get the defaults back. Can anyone help me? Point me in the right direction?

Comment: I have the default repositories, just not the 'Other Software' repositories.

Comment: Other software will just be your installation media (*you don't need that once the system is installed so don't worry about that*).  Anything else there was added post-install so you'd have to ask people with `sudo` access on what was added; as *Other Software* sources is expected to be none (*or initial install media which is normally disabled*).